# Expose files created by a lambda function from an Elastic Beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I have a small application that build sitemap files from a lot of URLs (based on a Cron Job). I also have an Elastic Beanstalk application that run a web app.

I would like to keep them running separately, but I would like the web app to expose the created sitemaps.

I was thinking about using a lambda function to create the sitemaps, but I don't see how my Elastic Beanstalk web app could get the files once it's done, so I am not sure to have the good approach; at least, I am missing a piece of the architecture.

What do you think about this solution? How would you manage it in an AWS environment?

Answer (score 2):

The piece you are missing is S3. Have Lambda copy the files to S3 when they are created. Then you could serve them directly from S3 or have your Beanstalk application load them from S3.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be the following:

- Use a [scheduled event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) to create the sitemaps with Lambda.
- Let Lambda upload those sitemaps to S3
- Let Lambda push a message containing the sitemaps location to a SQS Queue

Your Elastic Beanstalk application can then process the messages and is e.g. able to expose your sitemaps directly from S3.